# Renaming files overwrites part of the filename

Tags: windows, command, rename

I ahve a directory full of files, and I want to rename each of them to have TA_ in front of the original file name.  file1.txt should be renamed to TA_file1.txt.  What I am getting is TA_e1.txt instead.

ren "c:*.txt" "TA_*.txt" is the command I am trying to use.

The file names are all of various lengths, and no matter what I try, it always overwrites the first 3 characters of my file name....

Answer (score 2):

A simple one liner would be:

```
for %i IN (*.txt) DO ren "%i" "TA_%i"
```

This loops over all files (*.txt) and passes their name in the `%i` variable to the `ren` command. `ren` can then use the `%i` content to expand it with your desired prefix.

The command will only work for files in the current directory. For more complex things you should write a batch file. Come back if you need help with that.

Comment: That works when we want to run it on the fly, but we are looking to automate it, so I think a batch file is in order here....

Comment: @Matt: replace "%" -> "%%" and you should do

Comment: @Matt: Okay then, do you need help on something?